# Can one disjoin any submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$ from itself by a $C^{\infty}$-small isotopy?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a manifold and $V$ be an oriented vector bundle. It's well known that if the Euler class of $V$ is non zero, then $V$ can't have a non-vanishing section. The converse is not true, see [Vanishing of Euler class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31376/vanishing-of-euler-class) , or the answer by John Klein below, given to the first version of this question. So:

**Question.** Recall that the normal bundle of a smooth orieantable submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$ always has zero Euler class.  Does such a normal bundle always has a non-vanishing section? If yes, how to prove this? If no, what is a counterexample?

**PS.** It turns out that this question is a subquestion of the following much more informed one: 
[Embeddings without nonvanishing normal vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80758/embeddings-without-nonvanishing-normal-vector-fields)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vanishing of Euler class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31376/vanishing-of-euler-class)

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for pointing to the previous question on mathoverflow. In the current form my question is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: Probably because my differential geometry is not so strong, but I can’t see what your question has to do with your title.

Comment: @LSpice Image of the section would be another copy of the manifold not intersecting the original. But I agree the title could be better

Comment: I think the title is fine; indeed they are the same question. The question feels like it should have a counterexample but I don't know one. Of course it is true in codimension 2.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that the submanifold is orientable, so that its normal bundle is orientable?

Comment: Yes, thank you, the submanifold should be orientable

Comment: For anyone wondering why the normal bundle has Euler class zero (as I was), this is Corollary $11.4$ of *Characteristic Classes* by Milnor & Stasheff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a counter example. Take any embedding of $\mathbb{C} P^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^7$ (such embeddings exist by

*Steer, B.*, [**On the embedding of projective spaces in Euclidean space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-21.3.489), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 21, 489-501 (1970). [ZBL0206.25501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0206.25501);

the construction is summarised [in this answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1927022/31046)).

If such an embedding admits a normal vector field, then by the [Compression Theorem of Rourke and Sanderson](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301356) it is isotopic to an embedding with normal field parallel to the last coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^7=\mathbb{R}^6\times\mathbb{R}$, and then the projection is an immersion $\mathbb{C} P^2\looparrowright \mathbb{R}^6$. Such immersions cannot exist, by András Szűcs' answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136924/8103).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, that's really cute. May I ask you to comment on the answer of Andras? He writes that if there exists an immersion of $\mathbb CP^2$ to $\mathbb R^6$  then "the normal Euler class has the property, that its square is the normal Pontrjagin class, and that is $−3$ times the signature".  I am rusty with Pontriagin classes so can't understand this line...

Comment: @aglearner: Thanks! Andras is using 3 facts about Pontrjagin classes, all of which can be found in Chapter 15 of Milnor and Stasheff: The square of the Euler class of a $2k$ dimensional bundle equals $p_k$; the Pontragin classes satisfy a sum formula $p(E\oplus F) = p(E)p(F)$ modulo $2$-torsion; and $p_1(\mathbb{C}P^2) = 3a^2$, where $a\in H^2(\mathbb{C} P^2)$ is the generator.

Comment: (The sum formula implies that $p_1(\nu)=-3a^2$ where $\nu$ is the hypothetical normal bundle which has $\nu\oplus T\mathbb{C} P^2$ a trivial bundle.)

Comment: Thanks again, Mark, really happy to learn all this!

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of counter-examples.

Here's one:
The fibration $\text{SO}(3) \to \text{SO}(4) \to S^3$ splits, since it is the principal bundle of the tangent bundle of $S^3$, and the latter is parallelizable. In particular,  $\pi_5(\text{SO}(4)) \cong \pi_5(\text{SO}(3)) \oplus \pi_5(S^3) \cong \Bbb Z/2 \oplus \Bbb Z/2$ .

Let $a$ and $b$ denote the generators for the summands. Then $(a,b)$ determines a rank $4$-vector bundle over $S^6$ with trivial Euler class (since $H^4(S^6) = 0$). But 
this vector bundle does not have a section, for if it did that would lead to the contradiction that $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you John. I edited the question, because I do want to know the answer to a part of the original question, which was not covered in the previous question on mathoverflow.

Comment: @aglearner, is your question about a submanifold in an arbitrary manifold or a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Dean, my original question was more general, and John immediately gave a counterexample, which illustrates that vanishing of the Euler class doesn't guarantee existence of a non-vanishing section. However, since I really want the answer to my question above (about submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$), I decided to modify the original question. So now John's answer doesn't answer the current question, but it nicely illustrates it.